# Jquery Featherlight js. Customized CSS radio button not working in modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use customized radio/option button. It is working fine with html page. When i try to use same thing in modal window (Feather light js modal window). Not able to click customized radio button.
Plain html radio button is working in modal window.

Any suggestion/idea will be great help
please check my 
[code here, or below](http://jsfiddle.net/dsriniudt/JNsu6/264/)
Click inline link in result window to analyze the issue...

```
<a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4069/4563624740_93430bb907_b.jpg" data-featherlight>Nice image</a>

<hr>

<a href=".inline" data-featherlight>Inline</a>

<div class="inline">Hello, world<br>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="selector">
    <label for="f-option">Pizza</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="s-option" name="selector">
    <label for="s-option">Boyfriend</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="t-option" name="selector">
    <label for="t-option">Cats</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<hr>

<h3>Gallery</h3>
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
  <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_b.jpg"><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_q.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_3403152632_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_f652202d1b_q.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_q.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inline { display: none }

ul li{
  color: #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
}

ul li input[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

ul li:hover label{
    color: #ddd;
}

ul li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: border .25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #ddd;
}

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
    content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
    transition: background 0.25s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #0DFF92;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #0DFF92;
}
```

Comment: Please post a test case which replicates the issue

Comment: Created fiddle ..
http://jsfiddle.net/dsriniudt/JNsu6/264/

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue

```
ul li input[type=radio]{
   position: absolute;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you change the above to:

```
ul li input[type=radio]{
   opacity:0;
   left:20px;
   top:30px;
   z-index:10;
}
```

This effectively places the original radio button over the top of your custom one which makes it clickable.